# python's ENUM values not correct

Tags: python, enums

I have the following Enum class:

```
class Features(Enum):
    Feature0 = auto()
    Feature1 = auto()
    Feature2 = auto()
    Feature3 = auto()
    Feature4 = auto()
    Feature5 = auto()
    Feature6 = auto()
    Feature7 = auto()
    Feature8 = auto()
    Feature9 = auto()
    Feature10 = auto()
    Feature11 = auto()
```

At some point further down the line I test Feature10 and I get the following:

```
feature_test = Features.Feature10
Features.Feature10 == feature_test
>> False
```

When printing the values I observe the following:

```
feature_test.value, Feature10.value
>>> 11, 10
```

What's going on there? Have I somehow messed the value of the IntEnum class up?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. But I would expect that Feature10.value would be 11 because it is the eleventh element of your enum. Please post a [mre].

Comment: "At some point further down the line" seems to mean ... "at some point, after intervening code that I don't include in the question ...". The code that you actually posted doesn't behave in the way that you says it behaves. Please make sure that you *test* that your code is a [mcve] before posting it.

Answer (score 3):

The question itself is not very clear:

- you inherited from `Enum`, but talk about `IntEnum` at the end
- your middle section of code `feature_test = Features.Feature10; Features.Feature10 == feature_test` *cannot* fail (but you show that it did)

However, your print of

```
>>> feature_test.value, Feature10.value
11, 10
```

while not copy/pasted, does offer an important clue:

The problem you are experiencing is due to one of the several differences between `Enum` and typical Python objects:  numbering in enums starts with `1`, not `0`.

To get the results you are expecting, you need to set the first value:

```
class Features(IntEnum):
    feature0 = 0
    feature1 = auto()
    feature2 = auto()
    ...
```